# How do I sort a dictionary containing lists of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, sorting

my data looks like this:

```
    data = {'field1': [{'id': <some-string>,
                        'x': <number-to-sort-on>}, ...],
            'field2': [{'id': <some-string>,
                        'x': <some-number>}, ...]
            ... }
```

Basically I want to take as input the field name ('field1', 'field2', etc). My code should then sort the list of dictionaries (desc order) for that field based on the 'x' value.  However, I also am trying to have all other 'fields' update according to the original sort.  Let me give an example.

```
   data = {'field1': [{'id': 'firstID', 'x': 3}, {'id': 'secondID', 'x': 6}],
           'field2': [{'id': 'firstID', 'x': 4}, {'id': 'secondID', 'x': 1}]}
```

Upon receiving an input of 'field1', a sort operation should transform my data to the following:

```
   data = {'field1': [{'id': 'secondID', 'x': 6}, {'id': 'firstID', 'x': 3}],
           'field2': [{'id': 'secondID', 'x': 1}, {'id': 'firstID', 'x': 4}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
field_value = data['field1']                 # extract the value for the input field name

for k,v in data.items():
    # sort the values for each key based on the values of the extracted fields
    sorted_value = sorted(enumerate(v), key=lambda (i, _): field_value[i]['x'], reverse=True)
    data[k] = [v[1] for v in sorted_value]

data
# {'field1': [{'id': 'secondID', 'x': 6}, {'id': 'firstID', 'x': 3}],
#  'field2': [{'id': 'secondID', 'x': 1}, {'id': 'firstID', 'x': 4}]}
```

Another option similar to the `argsort()` method of numpy, you can obtain a list of index which sorts the value corresponding to `field1` and then use the list of index to sort all other values:

```
field_value = data['field1']
argsort_lst = [i for i, _ in sorted(enumerate(field_value), key=lambda (i,v): v['x'], reverse=True)]

argsort_lst
# [1, 0]

for v in data.values():
    v[:] = [v[i] for i in argsort_lst]

data
# {'field1': [{'id': 'secondID', 'x': 6}, {'id': 'firstID', 'x': 3}],
#  'field2': [{'id': 'secondID', 'x': 1}, {'id': 'firstID', 'x': 4}]}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I have a follow-up question - say instead of receiving a single field as input, I'm given a list of fields and the order determines the order of my sorting. So if I was given ['field1', 'field2'] I would first sort data based on your algorithm, but in cases where 'field1' values are equal (say all have 'x': 5), I should sort the 'field2' values in desc order and this update should be reflected in all other fields.  Any ideas?

Comment: In that case make both the `field_value` and the `key` tuples. For instance, something like for the first option: `field_value = zip(data['field1'], data['field2']); sorted(enumerate(v), key=lambda (i, _): (field_value[i][0]['x'], field_value[i][1]['x']), reverse=True)`